# Full text search matching only certain words?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I have started using SqLite recently, so I am relatively new to it. I am trying to use the full text search feature to find rough matches for a chat robot. Basically I want to match as many keywords as possible, but not necessarily all of them. The results should be sorted based on how many keywords were found in the phrase and how closely ordered they are to the query. In other words the ordering doesn't have to be exact, but the closer it is, the higher the result should rank. Similarly, even if only one or two words in the phrase are found it should match, but rank higher the more of the words that are present. I have read the reference and I see the NEAR statement and the matchinfo function, as well as the example of how to use it, but I cannot figure out how to apply this knowledge to my specific problem. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The reason I have trouble accepting answers is because I am blind, and the screen reading software I am using is not finding the accept button. It seems to be using some sort of dhtml, rather than being a regular link or button (it just appears as text, so I can't activate it). I have recently emailed the Stack Overflow team about this.

Comment: Understood. I hope they can remedy it for you. Sorry I do not have an answer for your question.

Comment: Seems the Stack Overflow people have fixed this now. I can accept answers at long last.

Comment: @user749473 Is it alright to use character distance as an approximation?  I'm not entirely sure that you couldn't obtain the word distance from the auxiliary tables either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently been told that this is not possible on the SqLite mailing list. The closest I came to a solution was to strip out stop words like a search engine would, as well as using the porter stemmer algorithm to further generalize queries. Searching first for the full set of keywords (naturally without punctuation and similar), then searching for the same set of keywords with stemming applied, then searching for the same set but with stop words stripped, and finally searching for this same stripped subset with stemming applied, seems to give a reasonable approximation from best to worst. Of course as soon as some matches are found, the more general queries that follow in the chain above are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can get this information via the `offsets` auxiliary function.  Here is a link to more complete documentation:

[4.1. The Offsets Function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_1)

Basically you add the function to your query and it will return the offsets within the document.

```
SELECT offsets(data) FROM data ...
```

Each result is a space separated list of 4 integers.  The third column is the byte offset of the matching term within the column.  You should be able to craft a solution with that information.

Here is a transcript of some exploratory queries.

```
sqlite> create virtual table data using fts4(body);

sqlite> insert into data(body) 
  values('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

sqlite> insert into data(body) 
  values('the lazy brown fox quickly jumps over the lazy dog');

sqlite> select * from data where body match 'lazy';
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
the lazy brown fox quickly jumps over the lazy dog

sqlite> select rowid,offsets(data) from data where body match 'brown';
1|0 0 10 5
2|0 0 9 5

sqlite> select rowid,offsets(data) from data where body match 'lazy';
1|0 0 35 4
2|0 0 4 4 0 0 42 4
```

So if you wanted to search for brown vs lazy, both of these documents match.

For the first document, brown is at 10 and lazy is at 35.  They are 25 apart.

For the second document brown is at 9 and lazy is at 4 and 42.  They are 5 and 33 apart.

They also reference term ordering of the predicate, though it isn't working when I try to match two terms in the same query.  I am not sure if I am misunderstanding or if I just don't know the correct semantics.

I suspect there is some SQL pivot shenanigans that you could use to do all the ranking calculations within sqlite.  Getting the results out of sqlite and just do the ranking math yourself is probably more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

This the sql query u can u use....

```
Select * 
From Tablename 
Where Yourfield = '"+textbox.text(or any data)+"%'
```

this will give u all data of that field starting with leter or number in the textbos or whatever u want

eg:-
u enter t
it will give 
t
tea
tisha

ot numbers too 
u enter 1
u will gwt 1
112
1
13

Comment: This seems to be a query that matches parts of words. I am looking for a solution that allows me to match entire words, but not necessarily all the ones present in the query. I'd like to match, say, more than 2 of the words if possible but not all of them have to match. Does that make sense?

Comment: Be Specific , give examples and research more